# Is this value of Critical Reynolds Number also valid for non circular ducts?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, convection

The flow remains laminar in case of internal flow through pipes up to a Reynolds number of 2300, for most practical cases. Is this value valid only for circular pipes or even for non circular ducts?

Comment: What length scale would you use to calculate the Reynolds number for a non-circular duct?

Comment: 4(c/s area)/ wetted perimeter. For a rectangular duct, 2ab/a+b, a and being length of sides of cross section.

Comment: If I recall correctly, this approach will give a pretty good approximation to the critical Re, although there will be some variations.  Google transition to turbulence for rectangular ducts and see what comes up.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I just read in 'Fundamentals of heat transfer by Incropera'. That 2300 serves as a good approximation, even for non circular conduits.